# Array.prototype.indexOf being added to end of arrays in IE8

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I know IE8 and earlier doesn't have an indexOf function. I'm defining it as follows:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
         for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
             if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}
```

I can correctly get the index of values in an array, but the function is being added to the end of my arrays when using IE8 and earlier. Therefore, I'm getting things like:

```
obj.obj2[0] = 'data'
obj.obj2[1] = 'other data'
obj.obj2['indexOf'] = [definition of indexOf function]
```

Not surprisingly, this is breaking everything else on the site. Problem isn't happening in IE10 or 9.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: It's being added neither to the beginning nor the end. It's just another inherited property. Only way this will be an issue is if you're using `for-in` to iterate your arrays, which is generally a bad idea as you can see.

Comment: We're using plain old for loops to iterate through arrays.

Comment: Then I don't understand what the issue is. I mean clearly you do want to have that method accessible from your Arrays as a property, otherwise it wouldn't be very useful. So the only time you should stumble on it should be during a `for-in` loop. Could you please describe the situation where this is causing a problem? Certainly you're not suggesting that `obj.obj2['indexOf']` is the problem, are you?

Comment: Filter all your `for..in` loops with `if (object.hasOwnProperty(property))` or don't extend the `Array.prototype` and use it as a stand alone function. On newer browsers you can define the method on the prototype using `Object.defineProperty` to make sure that it is not enumerable.

Comment: @Xotic750: Why would you use `for-in` on an Array in the first place?

Comment: I wouldn't, unless there was a good reason for it.

Comment: @Xotic750: Oh, all right. I must have misunderstood what you were suggesting.

Comment: I'm not using for...in loops. Also, IE8 and earlier don't have an indexOf function, so I don't have much of a choice in whether or not I define indexOf. The problem isn't in newer browsers, I'm working specifically IE8 and IE7 (thankfully not IE6). Chrome, firefox, safari are working perfectly well.

Comment: Then I think you need to explain more about your problem. Create a scenario on jsfiddle for us too look at and post the scenario code here in your question. Other wise there is nothing wrong, because as you defined `indexOf` on `Array.prototype`, sure it will show if you do `[]["indexOf"]`, just like if you did `[]["slice"]`

Comment: @user2144960 Did you fix this problem? Your description of the problem is basically the result of a `for ... in` loop and then you go and state that you don't use that (twice). It doesn't add up. The reason why `.indexOf` would not show up in `for ... in` for newer browsers is because you didn't add it manually, it's a built in function. If you're using `for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){` then you would be save or do like Xotic750 suggested and use `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: Please show an exact code example which fails with this array.

Answer (score 1):

It is added to the prototype, so everytime you treat your array like an object (`for..in` loop is one example), it will show up. It does not show up in other browsers because they already have the `indexOf` method by default, so you're not modifying the prototype.

You can use [`obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to test whether a property is defined directly on your object (in this case, your array, which is an object basically) or somewhere else in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be doing something wrong when iterating through your arrays. I ran the following in IE8 and didn't get the behavior you mentioned:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
         for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
             if (this[i] === obj) { return i + " used prototype"; }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}

var myCars=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");
document.write(myCars.indexOf("Volvo") + "<br/><br/>");

for (i = 0; i < myCars.length; i++)
    document.write(i + ": " + myCars[i] + "<br/>");
```

output:

```
1 used prototype

0: Saab
1: Volvo
2: BMW
```

Comment: Using the idnexOf function itself is fine. I'm just wondering why IE8 is showing that there's an array item with the key 'indexOf'

Comment: That's how prototyping works. You are adding a new object(in this case a function) to all objects of type Array. Here is a pretty good explaintion of how prototyping works: [link](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/)

Answer (score 0):

In the case when we use Array.prototype.someFunction,
to filter truly array's elements in IE 8, we can use:

```
for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (typeof myArray[i] === "function") {break;}

    // some code for myArray trully elements
}
```

Answer (score -2):

IE<9 doesn't have an `.indexOf()` function for Array, to define the exact spec version, run this before trying to use it:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, or is it?

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question. -1 (will remove it once you update the answer)

Comment: @EpokK Seems like better code, no problem with that. But we have a question here, and I suspect using this code will not solve the OP's problem. Please explain me if I'm wrong.